# Creating a button with user-selected image in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I'm creating a Java Application which lets the User click a button that opens a File Selector and upon selecting an image creates a Button with that image and text from a Text Field. It's working without the image but I can't figure out how to add an image to the button for the life of me.

Context: `btns` is a GridPane of Buttons, `lastTopIn` is an integer that keeps track of the last used column of the GridPane. The button removes itself when clicked.

```
FileChooser fc = new FileChooser()
fc.setTitle("Choose Image for Button");
File file = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
lastTopIn++;
Button thebutton = new Button((String) tf.getText(), new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("file://"+file.getAbsolutePath()))));
    thebutton.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<Event>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(Event event) {
            btns.getChildren().remove(thebutton);                           
        }
    });
btns.add(thebutton, lastTopIn,1);
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I think this is wrong `getClass().getResourceAsStream("file://"+file.getAbsolutePath())`. Not 100% sure though.

Comment: Off-topic: don't use `setOnMouseClicked` on a  button; use `setOnAction` instead.

Comment: @James_D Where's the difference?

Comment: @LW001 The difference will be pretty important if the user tries to trigger the button with the keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display an image from a file on the file system, convert the file to a URI, instead of trying to load it as a resource:

```
Button thebutton = new Button(tf.getText(), 
    new ImageView(new Image(file.toURI().toString())));
```

`file.ToURI()` will create the correct URI scheme, as well as properly escaping any characters such as whitespace that are legal in filenames but illegal in URIs.

Note that, as a shortcut, you can pass the URI directly to the `ImageView` constructor, and it will create the image for you:

```
Button thebutton = new Button(tf.getText(), new ImageView(file.toURI().toString()));
```